# import csv file to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, scala, csv, playframework

I want to import a csv file from my interface and to automatically insert data from the csv file to my collection in mongodb using reactiveMongo scala and play framework. I searched in the internet and I found a lot of informations so I don't know how to start which library, component I have to use any advice or example please?

Comment: Have you looked at MongoImport in the docs?

Comment: yes, but is that all what I need? to do an import (from an interface of administration) of csv file wich contains a list of contact that will be insert in the database.

Comment: @Rajeun were you ablr to do it ?

Comment: @M.AhsenTaqi No I worked with angular-js-xlsx for xls files and it's work fine